# Why are some jet trails longer and some shorter?

Tags: contrails

One can see  jet trails behind an airplane. I know that they form because of rapid condensation of Jet exhaust. But I can't figure out why some remain for too long time (hence, longer) while  some are smaller and disappear rapidly.  Does this depend on height of airplane or some other parameter ?

Comment: Hey thanks, for the answer. Can you tell me, how can I delete my question now?

Comment: @AbhishekVerma We prefer if duplicate questions remain, it helps broaden the surface area that searches will reach and helps point people to the correct answer.